# Bootstrap dropdown text vertical center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap dropdown and it looks like this with my css style:

```
.project .versions {
    height: 25px !important;
}
```

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to center the selected item?

[image]

Comment: Centered horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Use `padding` and `margin`. Chrome's inspect can be very useful. If you paste a fiddle, it is even more helpful than just a snippet of css

Answer (score 1):

Try vertical centering with `line-height`

```
.project .versions {
    height: 25px !important;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting `line height: 12px;` It will be good if you share your code snippet here.